# 2FA Setup for FortiGate SSL VPN

Tags: firewall, fortigate, fortinet, sslvpn

Just wanted to inquire if there is a way with FortiGate 60E to setup 2FA without setting-up a Forti-Authenticator or any additional costs?  We are currently using this FW for our SSL VPN in our small office and wanted to increase security for users via 2FA.

Using SonicWalls before and it has an option to do SMS or eMail for FREE.  Just hoping FortiGates have this as well.

Cheers!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure email 2FA for a user like this:

```
#config user local
    edit {username}
       set type password
       set two-factor email
       set email-to {user_email_address}
       set passwd {password}
    next
end
```

https://kb.fortinet.com/kb/documentLink.do?externalID=FD45585

SMS or certificate authentication is also possible: https://www.fortinetguru.com/2016/06/two-factor-authentication/

Finally, you can use a RADIUS server with any kind of authentication behind it, but that is a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following options:

- E-Mail Token: https://community.fortinet.com/t5/FortiGate/Technical-Tip-Email-Based-two-factor-Authentication/ta-p/193019
- SMS Token: https://community.fortinet.com/t5/FortiGate/Technical-Tip-SMS-Two-Factor-Authentication/ta-p/196455
- FortiToken: https://docs.fortinet.com/document/fortigate/7.2.1/administration-guide/332870/add-fortitoken-multi-factor-authentication

As @Zac67 already mention you have also the possibility to solve it with RADIUS (Challange) or Certificate.

On top you have the option to intergrate Azure MFA over SAML (for sure all other SAML solutions works as well): https://docs.fortinet.com/document/fortigate-public-cloud/6.2.0/azure-administration-guide/584456/configuring-saml-sso-login-for-ssl-vpn-with-azure-ad-acting-as-saml-idp